# Make edit to object at same memory location - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, is there a way to edit an object on the same memory location, rather than creating a new version of the object? For example, if I have a DataFrame (just as an example), can I add a column to it without creating a copy of the DataFrame first?

```
df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,4]],columns=['a','b','c'])
id(df)
Output: 135033184L


df = df[['a','b']]
id(df)
Output: 40836008L
```

(My thinking is by creating a copy, I'll just have double the memory usage for one object. Let me know if that's faulty thinking though!)

Comment: It all depends on the object. Strings? No. Lists and dictionaries? Yes. Tkinter widgets? Yes. And so on.

Comment: In Python the cleverness of some data structure implementations brings some volatility in memory usage. Sample: A list does pre-allocate some space in addition to what an initial length/filling requires, so appending "a few" entries is cheao and should be somehow homogeneous in memory, but then comes an append, where the whole space get's copied into a new larger memory area (by copy) which takes seom time, but starts a new optimized (auq performance) fast append. That is my folklore on a late European evening ...)

Comment: @BryanOakley, shouldn't lists and dictionaries generally be references unless otherwise specified? Looking for pandas DataFrames/numpy arrays specifically.

Comment: Yes, a list contains references to objects. However, you can add items to a list without making a copy of the list. Isn't that what you're asking -- if there are objects that can be edited without first making a copy?